# Move cursor to beginning of non-whitespace characters in a line in Vim

Tags: vim, gvim, macvim

In Vim, is there a way to move the cursor to the beginning of non-whitespace characters in a line? For instance, how can I move the cursor to the "S" in the second line below?

```
First line
    Second line
```

If it matters, I primarily use MacVim, but I'd also like to be able to do this from the console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If I understand correctly - from `:h ^`:

```
^ To the first non-blank character of the line.
  |exclusive| motion.
```

(in contrast to `0`, which gets you to the beginning, regardless of whitespace or not)

Comment: +1 on the `0` comment

Answer (score 82):

Instead of pressing `^` you can press `_`(underscore) to jump to the first non-whitespace character on the same line the cursor is on.

`+` and `-` jump to the first non-whitespace character on the next / previous line.

(These commands only work in normal mode, not in insert mode.)

Comment: Can also use `<CR>` as an alternative to `+`, which is nice because it doesn't require holding shift.

Comment: For a discussion about the **difference** between the `^` and `_` motions, [**see here**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155926/39845).

Answer (score 14):

Also possibly useful: `+` and `-` will move the cursor up or down, respectively, to the first non-blank character.

Answer (score 7):

below is a snippet from by .vimrc
`^[[1~` is created by pressing `ctrl+v` and `Home`

```
"jump to first non-whitespace on line, jump to begining of line if already at first non-whitespace
map <Home> :call LineHome()<CR>:echo<CR>
imap <Home> <C-R>=LineHome()<CR>
map ^[[1~ :call LineHome()<CR>:echo<CR>
imap ^[[1~ <C-R>=LineHome()<CR>
function! LineHome()
  let x = col('.')
  execute "normal ^"
  if x == col('.')
    execute "normal 0"
  endif
  return ""
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for. This behaviour is common on editors nowadays (Atom/VSCode/Sublime to name a few) and I've gotten used to it...

Answer (score 1):

I just remap the 0 key to ^

Edit your ~/.vimrc

```
set visualbell t_vb=
map 0 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Andrew Sohn's answer, if you'd like to use 0 for this behavior, just wrap it like so:

```
function! LineHome()
  let x = col('.')
  execute "normal ^"
  if x == col('.')
    unmap 0
    execute "normal 0"
    map 0 :call LineHome()<CR>:echo<CR>
  endif
  return ""
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

And just for completeness, here is the dual of Andrew Sohn's Answer:

```
" jump to the last non-whitespace char on line, or eol if already there
map <End> :call LineEnd()<CR>:echo<CR>
imap <End> <C-R>=LineEnd()<CR>
function! LineEnd()
  let x = col('.')
    execute "normal g_"
  if x == col('.')
    execute "normal $"
  endif
 return ""
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Vi Reference Card](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/Tutorials/Reference/virefcard.pdf) under Motion:

next word, blank delimited word <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>

beginning of word, of blank delimited word <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>